# difference "im Übrigen" and "für den Rest"

Tags: usage

I would like to know the difference between these two terms please. 
(I am trying to translate the "Pour le reste" structure in french. But für den Rest does not sound very good to me).

EDIT: 
should you for instance say "Im übrigen, alles wie gewohnt", or "Für den Rest, alles wie gewohnt"

Comment: Do you have an example? A sentence you want to translate?

Comment: thx, I edited my question

Comment: With example we mean something what makes the context clearer. Who is meant with "reste".  Are these persons, is this an agenda, is this a task list?

Comment: Ich kann kein Französisch und kenne den Kontext nicht, aber würde "ansonsten" passen?

Comment: @Robert : ich glaube ansonsten passt tatsächlich am besten. Danke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @PerlDuck got the difference between *im Übrigen* (capitalized, adverbial use) and *für den Rest* right, there is still *im übrigen* as well, which is used as an adjective and means *restlich*.

> - Im Übrigen ist das Bundesgebiet in 16 Bundesländer aufgeteilt, nicht in 15.
> - Im übrigen Bundesgebiet gelten andere Gesetze.

Adverbial use (*Im Übrigen*, capitalized) is a synonym for *darüber hinaus* or *nebenbei erwähnt*, while in its adjective form (*Im übrigen*, lowercase) it means *restlich*.

Answer (score 2):

The two terms mean something <strike>completely</strike> different:

- *Im Übrigen* means *by the way* (figurative) while
- *Für den Rest* simply means *for the rest* or *for the remainder* (physically)

> - Wir haben 12 Gäste, aber nur 8 Bratwürste.
>     Für den Rest machen wir Fisch.
>     (8 get bratwurst, the remaining 4 get fish)
> - Wir haben 12 Gäste eingeladen. Im Übrigen (=übrigens) gab es Fisch.
>     (We've invited 12 people for dinner. By the way, we had fish)

Perhaps you are mixing up ***im** Übrigen* and ***die** Übrigen*.
That's again different:

> - Wir haben 12 Gäste, aber nur 8 Bratwürste.
>     Die Übrigen [Gäste] bekommen Fisch.
>     (8 get bratwurst, the remaining 4 get fish)

So *die Übrigen* is more or less synonym with *der Rest*, but *im Übrigen* is not.

Comment: Correct. "im übrigen" could also mean something like "an sonsten" which translates to "other than that" .